# Problems with validation rules on Users

Tags: validation-rule, user

Been trying to set a validation rule on User Object where a field (Calendar_URL__c) becomes required for 2 specific profiles.

The validation rule doesn't get triggered, no error whatsoever.

here is the formula I came up :

```
AND(
    OR(
        $Profile.Name = "CSM (Lightning)",
        $Profile.Name = "Standard User Plus Enterprise (Lightning only)"
    ),
    ISBLANK(Calendar_URL__c)
)
```

get no syntax error but doesn't trigger the validation rules.

Comment: what is the type of Calendar_URL__c field?

Comment: found the mistake. was quite stupid. Calendar_URL__c is Link field. 

here is the functioning formula: 

AND(
    OR(
        Profile.Name = "CSM (Lightning)",
        Profile.Name = "Standard User Plus Enterprise (Lightning only)"
    ),
    ISBLANK(Calendar_URL__c)
)

there were 2 not needed $